# Can a shower surround be cut to fit a window?

Tags: shower

I was planning on putting a shower surround for my basement bathroom.   As you can see in the picture.....the surround will block part of the window.   Do I just leave it be and have it block, or can I cut that section out?   Think it depends on the type of surround I get[image]

Comment: yes, you can cut the surround no matter what it is made of .... there is a saw available for cutting practically any material imaginable

Comment: It is how you finish it out, making it shed water and not get behind the panel will be the trick